# Add strings to another string inside a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a for loop where i´m basically creating strings and inside the loop i have to concatenate the result of that loop to another string **BUT** I have to add it BEFORE the last string:

```
post_body_participants= "guest = ["
post = True
for i in bla:
    participants_body = 'nlaslda'
    if post:
        post_body_participants += participants_body
        post = False
    else:
        s = "add me before"
        (ADD "s" to post_body_participants before participants_body)
```

Any clue on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: please give expected output string.

Comment: Can you please give both a set of sample data and a sample output string?  I.e., `bla = ['bill', 'joe', 'cindy',]` and ...whatever your output string should look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
post_body_participants = s + post_body_participants
```